# CSS Grid Layout Is Overlapped by Any Following HTML Elements

Tags: html, css, svg, grid

The below HTML and CSS and SVG coding produces a proper CSS Grid Layout, but the small elements that follow it in the HTML appear as overlapping the Grid instead of following the grid.  This is an experimental status Mozilla standard, so must be run in Chrome Canary, or Mozilla Experimental, or amazingly in standard recent IE.

I have researched this question all over the web and the code shown follows examples there, but I cannot find any example of avoiding this overlap.

The codes:

```css
div.kybd-tries-pxfixed {
  color: black;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 3px dotted black;
  width: 200px; /* 300px; */
  height: 200px; /* 50px; */
  font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 3vh; /* 1.4rem;*/ /* 14px; */
  /* border: 5px solid black; */
}

#kybdgrd{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  page-break-after: always;
}

#kybdTryPxfixed-01-01   { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 1; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-02-01   { grid-column: 2; grid-row: 1; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-03-01   { grid-column: 3; grid-row: 1; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-04-01   { grid-column: 4; grid-row: 1; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-01-02   { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 2; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-02-02   { grid-column: 2; grid-row: 2; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-03-02   { grid-column: 3; grid-row: 2; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-04-02   { grid-column: 4; grid-row: 2; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-01-03   { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 3; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-02-03   { grid-column: 2; grid-row: 3; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-03-03   { grid-column: 3; grid-row: 3; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-04-03   { grid-column: 4; grid-row: 3; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-01-04   { grid-column: 1; grid-row: 4; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-02-04   { grid-column: 2; grid-row: 4; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-03-04   { grid-column: 3; grid-row: 4; }
#kybdTryPxfixed-04-04   { grid-column: 4; grid-row: 4; }
```

```html
<h1>Document Main Header, via the h1 tag.</h1>
<div id="kybdgrd">
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-01-01" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-02-01" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-03-01" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-04-01" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-01-02" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-02-02" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-03-02" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-04-02" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-01-03" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-02-03" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-03-03" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-04-03" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-01-04" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-02-04" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-03-04" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
  <div id="kybdTryPxfixed-04-04" class="kybd-tries-pxfixed"><img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<svg id="svgId99" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="50" y="50" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="20" fill="red" /></svg>' alt="Just a sample resize test." width="100%" /></div>
</div>
<p>
  Some foobar text.
</p>
<p>
  This is a foobar paragraph.
</p>
```

Comment: When I run this in Chrome I just see each div in a separate line. like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fHoi3.png

Comment: Ah, I forgot to say that this is an experimental status Mozilla standard!  My bad.  Must be run in Chrome Canary, or Mozilla Experimental, or amazingly in standard recent IE.  Editing my question now.

Comment: Your example seems to work as intended in both Firefox Developer Edition and Chrome Canary. Where exactly are you seeing this problem? Is the problem appearing in IE/Edge?